# React-Native:borderRadius not properly applied to child component (i.e Image), but the property is applied to touchableOpacity

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web, cross-platform

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const DashboardScreen=()=>{
    return (
        <View style={styles.outerView}>
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchableOpacityStyle}>
                        <Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={require('../../assets/images/beach.jpg')}></Image>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} style={styles.touchableOpacityStyle}>
                    <Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={require('../../assets/images/beach.jpg')}></Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} style={styles.touchableOpacityStyle}>
                    <Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={require('../../assets/images/beach.jpg')}></Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} style={styles.touchableOpacityStyle}>
                    <Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={require('../../assets/images/beach.jpg')}></Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} style={styles.touchableOpacityStyle}>
                    <Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={require('../../assets/images/beach.jpg')}></Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} style={styles.touchableOpacityStyle}>
                    <Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={require('../../assets/images/beach.jpg')}></Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    outerView:{
        flex:1,
        padding:12
    },
    viewStyle:{
        flexDirection:"row",
        justifyContent:"space-around",
        marginBottom:15
    },
    touchableOpacityStyle:{ 
        borderRadius:15,
        height:150,
        width:150
    },
    imageStyle:{
        flex:1,
        borderRadius:15
    }
});

export default DashboardScreen;
```

I want to include an image in a touchable component! I'm facing styling issues here as I'm new to React-Native. The border radius is getting applied to the touchable component but it isn't getting attached to the Image inside the touchable component. Is it because of flex-direction:"row" in the parent component(i.e TouchableOpacity)?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'resizeMode' prop for Image Component

```js
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchableOpacityStyle}>
                        <Image style={styles.imageStyle} resizeMode={'contain'} source={require('../../assets/images/beach.jpg')}></Image>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: No, this is just reducing image size overall, but I am not getting the required borderRadius of 15

Comment: You need to give the same height and width to Image component also as you have given to Your TouchableOpacity

Comment: Thanks! I just did that few moments ago.......forgot to update here .......LOL